# Adding List items to other person list by just wrirting person surname

Tags: javascript, html

I can search the person name and surname from the list and I can display the person's name and surname.For example: I have a person who called 'Agne Gabrielle' when I write only 'Gabrielle' to input field I could not display this person name and surname. Because my codes work only for when I write the person'full name.I tries to use split() method but I think I could not use properly so it did not work.
How can I fix this problem?
Thank you in advance.

HTML Codes

```js
const input = document.getElementById("the-filter");
const list = document.getElementById('the-list');
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const element = document.querySelector(".main-div");
const li = document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item');
const items = document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item');
const newList = document.querySelector('#myList');

const listDiv = document.querySelector('.list-container');

button.addEventListener('click', listName);

function listName() {

  element.style.visibility = "hidden";
  listDiv.style.visibility = "visible";

  const inputTrimmedLower = input.value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();


  input.value = "";
  input.focus();

  if (!inputTrimmedLower) {
    return;
  }


  for (const lis of items) {

    const liTrimmedLower = lis.textContent.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
    if ((liTrimmedLower === inputTrimmedLower)) {
      console.log(`${inputTrimmedLower} is already listed`);
      let newItem = document.createElement("li");
      newItem.classList.add("list-group-item");
      newItem.append(inputTrimmedLower);

      newList.prepend(newItem);

      input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        if (newList.childElementCount > 1) {
          if (newList.hasChildNodes()) {
            newList.removeChild(newList.childNodes[0]);

          }

        }

      });

      return;
    }
  }
}

input.addEventListener('keyup', search);

function search() {
  const inputTrimmedLower = input.value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();


  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if (li[i].innerHTML.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(inputTrimmedLower) ||
      li[i].innerHTML.toLocaleUpperCase().includes(inputTrimmedLower)) {
      li[i].style.display = "";

    } else {
      li[i].style.display = 'none';

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <input type="text" id="the-filter" placeholder="Search For..." />
  <div class="list-container container">
    <ul id="myList" class="list-group">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="button">
    <button class=" btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="button">Click</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list">
    <li class="list-group-item">Adele Ak</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Agne Gabrielle</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Alex Thomson</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Alice</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Anderson</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Anna</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: when I type Gabrielle it displays Agne Gabrielle

Comment: Yes it displays in search.When I add the click button I want to display full name in different div.In this part it did not work.

Comment: you are trying to add items to the list based on this condition `liTrimmedLower === inputTrimmedLower` which will only ever be true if the full name was typed into the input. Usually though it will be false since your search filters based on partial strings `'ag' === 'agne gabrielle'` -> false.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Yes that's true. Which method should I use to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various tweaks that could be made here - for instance in your search function:

```
function search() {
  const inputTrimmedLower = input.value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();


  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if (li[i].innerHTML.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(inputTrimmedLower) ||
      li[i].innerHTML.toLocaleUpperCase().includes(inputTrimmedLower)) {
      li[i].style.display = "";

    } else {
      li[i].style.display = 'none';

    }
  }
}
```

What's the point in the second clause of your if statement? You're converting the input string to lowercase on assignment to the variable, so this: `li[i].innerHTML.toLocaleUpperCase().includes(inputTrimmedLower)` will always return false... You could also use a conditional assignment, since you're doing nothing else in the if statement.

You can also tidy it up a little bit by doing a foreach (which might be marginally quicker). Those improvements would make your search function:

```
function search() {
    const inputTrimmedLower = input.value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();

    li.forEach(function(item) {
        item.style.display = item.innerHTML.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(inputTrimmedLower) ? "" : "none";
    });
}
```

As for your listName function, you're essentially saying that you want to find the listitems that contain the value entered by the user and append them to the new list? If so... why reinvent the wheel?

You can do something similar to your search function to find the elements:

```
function listName() {

    element.style.visibility = "hidden";
    listDiv.style.visibility = "visible";

    const inputTrimmedLower = input.value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();

    input.value = "";
    input.focus();

    li.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.innerHTML.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(inputTrimmedLower)){
           let newItem = createElement('li','new-list-group-item');
           newItem.append(item.innerHTML);
           newList.prepend(newItem);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I think your method will be beneficial for me:)